# ifconfig fixed ip address is lost after a while

Tags: networking, ifconfig

I'm using ubuntu LTS14.04 and I want to make some lab experiments with two computers and a switch.

Both computers are configured to start with DHCP but I want to assign two fixed ip addresses to each one. I use `ifconfig eth...` command.

After changing both addresses `ifconfig` shows the correct one but when trying a ping (both computers connected through a switch) one of them loses its configuration and a window with "network disconnected" (or similar) appears. And I have to use ifconfig again to fix the correct ip fixed address which will be lost again after some seconds.

The other computer keeps its fixed ip address without any problem.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the ip address in /etc/network/interfaces
https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration

Comment: And what's the difference with ifconfig method? Will it be stable?

Comment: it will be more permanent so if things restart settings are loaded from here(i think, not sure).